# Bigger video size (width/height) for YouTube Embeds

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to show a YouTube video with a custom width/height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this link](http://www.youtube.com/youtubeonyoursite) on YouTube's site:

> You can resize the player by editing the object width="425" and height="350" fields at both the beginning and end of the embedded player code. Make sure that the sizes you choose have the same ratio as the default numbers, so that the video doesn't get stretched—just multiply the width by 0.8235 to get the height.

In short, just edit the parameters used for the dimensions in the embed code, making sure you preserve the original aspect ratio.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was working on a Tumblr theme and you can't post videos larger than 500 pixels, but if you post them as a text post it works. Anyway, thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: The 0.8235 ratio is key. Thanks!

Comment: 0.8235 is the ratio for 17:14.  If your looking for 16:9, it's 0.5625 ;)